# Looking for elliptical display or modular display to approximate ellipse

Tags: display, touchscreen

I'm not very fluent in electrical engineering so please bear with my imagination.

Requirements: Photo realistic display, touch screen, approx 7x3 feet (2.1 m x 0.9 m).

Option 1: Do elliptical displays exist? Whether it be a tv or monitor or whatever. I feel that it may be possible to build such a display but there being no demand they simply are not built. Is there a company I could approach that could custom build such a display?

Option 2: are there rectangular modular displays that I could interface together to approximate an ellipse? Preferably with as little separation between each display as possible to mimic a larger display. And so that the images on the 1 display can flow smoothly between all the displays?

Sketch below: Inner ellipse is desired display area. Rectangle represents a normal retangular display. The 4 corners of the rectangular display can be seen sticking out from a 4 inch bezel shown here. The bezel would have to be about twice as wide to hide the corners. Which is an option but becomes a fairly large bezel.

[image]

Comment: They certainly can exist, e.g. http://auo.com/?sn=107&lang=en-US&c=8&n=563 for a tiny one. Custom-building is going to be horrifyingly expensive. Can't you just put a rectangular one behind a round bezel? Actually finding a specific product is technically off-topic here, unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean with "elliptical"? Can you make a sketch?

Comment: Edited to include sketch.

Comment: Can't you just take a rectangular one and frame it in an ellipse? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Did you check the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+display+shape&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=custom+lcd+shape) before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and lowest cost way to get touch displays this size is to use rear projection. With curved optics and mirrors the projector depth can be quite small (1 -2 feet). There are many examples such as from Draper: http://www.draperinc.com/projectionscreens/rearscreens.aspx
Microsoft's Perceptive Pixel also make rear projection touch screens this size.

With the availability of 4k projectors now, you could implement a quite high resolution large touch systems.

You could also build a large display of multiple edgeless touch enabled LCD monitors, but you can never quite do it without some gaps in the display. It also needs much more graphic compute power as the number of displays rises.